# Microsoft Z3 get relevant assignments

Tags: java, z3, smt, sat

How do I get only the relevant value assignments for the variables used after the z3 satisfiability check?

For example:

I have multiple assertions that are given as constraints to Z3 Sat Solver, whereas a single Boolean Expression that I need to check for whether it satisfies or not.

`Note: The assertion may contain variables which are not present/irrelevant in the Boolean Expression (Formula)`

The values assigned to the model contain the assignment for the assertion constraints as well which has no impact on the satisfiability of the Boolean Expression.

I can see in the module `smt.relevance: 2` as default value in z3 configuration.

How do I limit it only to the variables which have an impact on the Expression satisfiability?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, in general. A SAT solver will "heuristically" solve the constraints to find a satisfying assignment, and in general, you cannot control how that search proceeds. They do not find any sort of "minimal satisfying assignment."

You can restrict the output to contain only those variables that occur in the formula, and query for the values of those at the end. If your formula has a variable whose assignment is irrelevant to SAT, this technique will obviously not work, but it should get you far.

Comment: I agree with @alias, just ignore the extra variables in the models. Z3 can sometimes return models that don't specify values for all variables, but there are no guarantees about that and apparently it doesn't happen in your use case. If you need some sort of semantic check, you can just try to flip each of the variables and ask Z3 whether that still satisfies the formula and if yes, you know the value is irrelevant (there's no guarantee this will identify all irrelevant values though).

Comment: I had thought of trying what you had suggested @Christoph but when we flip and put the variable back, the permutations of the variables are very high and this didn't seem a efficient way to do it. Wanted to know if there are better way to do this?

Comment: This is a nice trick, but doesn't avoid the exponential search. Consider `(p & q) -> r`. If you set `p` to `False`, then `q` is irrelevant. If you set `q` to `False`, then `p` is irrelevant. This shows that not only there isn't any notion of "minimal" (`p` and `q` can be arbitrary formulas with incomparable sets of elements), there is also no guided search you can find to lead you to some notion of "most irrelevant." (Continued in the next comment..)

Comment: (continued) You can always go with the formula that has fewer number of variables at each step, but that's not guaranteed to reach minima either. (But would make a good heuristic.) Also, this is all assuming SAT with booleans, situation is more complicated if you've regular SMT with variables over arbitrary domains,